# Error String cannot be converted to JsonObject

Tags: android

I have code to show store like this . and i still learning about android ,

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_store)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
               Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                      editstoreActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra("phone", mPhoneNumber);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });
```

but it show error like this

```
10-05 12:17:56.149: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=shoop3.android.edu/.editstoreActivity (has extras) }
10-05 12:17:58.289: DEBUG/dalvikvm(957): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1530 objects / 274448 bytes in 208ms
10-05 12:17:59.649: ERROR/JSON Parser(957): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-05 12:17:59.669: DEBUG/Single Store Details(957): {"store":[{"id_user":"63","id_platform":"1","store_url":"url.com","store_desc":"wordpress","id_store":"42","store_logo":null,"store_name":"toko wordpress edit","store_curr":null},{"id_user":"63","id_platform":"2","store_url":"pres.com","store_desc":"prestashop","id_store":"43","store_logo":null,"store_name":"toko prestashop","store_curr":null}]}
10-05 12:18:00.899: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity shoop3.android.edu/.editstoreActivity: 4664 ms (total 4664 ms)
10-05 12:18:58.339: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-05 12:23:58.343: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I really confuse , any solution?? please

Comment: what data is in `mPhoneNumber`? Is it a String or a JSON object?

Comment: sorry its a JsonObject , mPhoneNumber is a String , can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are possibly trying to convert a JSON to String . Try using Gson . It has methods to convert the JSON to string

Comment: Download Gson jar(http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.code.gson/gson/1.4) . Include it in your project .Then you can use the following code: Gson gson = new Gson(); String yourString = gson.toJson(yourJSONObject);

Comment: Gson is just an additional library to help convert JSON object to String . Rest of the coding will remain the same .

Comment: it solved , yup i use GSON , thanks all :)) , u really help me

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse response in json, where response is in xml, I assume.
Better, you use some XML parser, like

1. SAX Parser
2. DOM Parser
3. XMLPULL Parser